# tomcat is ignoring the 'factory' attribute on a Resource

Tags: java, tomcat

In my server.xml, I'm defining a resource:

```
<Resource name="global" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          maxTotal="100" maxIdle="30" maxWaitMillis="10000"
          username="user" password="betterThanThis"
          factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
          driverClassName="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver"
          url="jdbc:derby:memory:test;create=true"/>
```

In my webapp context.xml I'm linking to it:

```
<ResourceLink name="local"
              auth="Container"
              global="global"
              type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
```

In my web.xml I'm referencing it

```
<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>local</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

And in my code, I'm using it

```
DataSource ds = InitialContext.doLookup("java:/comp/env/local");
ds.getConnection();
```

That last line throws an exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2167) ~[tomcat8-dbcp-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:2037) ~[tomcat8-dbcp-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1543) ~[tomcat8-dbcp-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
```

Question: Why is a class in the `org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2` package throwing an error when I've specified `factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"` on my Resource?

It's not a missing jar problem, because I can see the Derby init in tomcat's logs. I don't think it's a naming issue, because when I change the name in `InitialContext.doLookup("java:/comp/env/local")` I get a naming error.

Edit: Full stack trace as requested:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:315) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2151) ~[tomcat8-dbcp-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Wrapped by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2167) ~[tomcat8-dbcp-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:2037) ~[tomcat8-dbcp-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1543) ~[tomcat8-dbcp-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at com.moosemorals.webmail.Database.getConnection(Database.java:46) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.moosemorals.webmail.Database.getAccountForAlias(Database.java:55) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.moosemorals.webmail.authserver.PostfixLookupServer.lookup(PostfixLookupServer.java:61) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.moosemorals.webmail.authserver.PostfixLookupServer.execute(PostfixLookupServer.java:40) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.moosemorals.webmail.authserver.GenericServer$Client.run(GenericServer.java:151) [classes/:na]
```

Comment: Please post full stack trace.

Comment: You are also using the Apache DBCP 2.x factory parameters: `maxTotal` and `maxWaitMillis` with the Tomcat JDBC factory. This won't work. You will need to change it back to `maxActive` and `maxWait` for them to work correctly.

Comment: Has this ever been solve? I have been fighting the same problem for several days.

Answer (score 0):

It says "No suitable driver" so you may be missing some derby jdbc jar. Putting it in Tomcat lib may be needed.